# How to sort BLE devices based on their RSSI?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am able to scan ble devices and display them. I am getting their RSSI values also. But I need to sort these devices in the recycler view by signal strength (strongest to weakest) and display different signal symbol beside each scanned device. Any idea how to accomplish that?

What to substitute the cases number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) by?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ScannedDevice device = list.get(position);

    holder.firmwareTv.setText(device.getFirmwareName());
    holder.macTv.setText(device.getMacId());

    int value = device.getRssi();

    switch (value){
        case 1:
            holder.signalIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_signal_full);
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.signalIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_signal_almost_full);
            break;
        case 3:
            holder.signalIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_signal_half);
            break;
        case 4:
            holder.signalIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_signal_first);
            break;
        case 5:
            holder.signalIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_signal_null);
            break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that devices with stronger signal strength `RSSI` have bigger int number. So you can sort your list that you give in your adapter.

You can do this before creating your adapter inside your controller . For example

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(yourList);
```

You can sort this List with filters like that with Java 8 :

```
sortedBLEDevices = 
yourList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ScannedDevice::getRssi)) // sort by Rssi
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```